# Excel VBA - format a whole column excluding the heading line

Tags: excel, formatting, vba

I want to format a column but to exclude the first row as this is the header:

My current Code is:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless the header is a number you shouldn't need to do this, I don't think.  The number format won't affect text (at least not much).  But here's a way:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Columns(3).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(cells(2,3), cells(2,3).end(xldown)).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```

This would select not the entire column, but the range from your first to last non-blank row.  If you have empty cells in between your first and last row, this is not an appropriate solution, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Starting cell").Entirecolumn.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just go back and reformat the first cell after you format the column.
This will avoid issues with blank cells.

```
Dim dTab As Worksheet
Set dTab = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

dTab.Columns(3).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
dTab.Range("C1").NumberFormat = "m/dd/yy" 'or whatever
```