# Change column strings to dates QUICKLY

Tags: excel, vba, date, text, format

I have a column of dates in, I believe, a text format, e.g.
 11/1/2014 or 12/30/2015
I want to change these to be a format I can do a vlookup on.

I have something that works, but is very slow (a minute or so):

```
Dim tmp As Integer
For tmp = 8 To lastRow
     Range("A" & tmp).Value = CDate(Range("A" & tmp).Value)
Next tmp
```

lastRow is set elsewhere in my program (typical value is 2000).  Is there a way to speed this up?  Another approach that produces the same result?

I'm imagining something along the lines of changing the whole column at once, such as done here: [Excel VBA - format a whole column excluding the heading line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730842/excel-vba-format-a-whole-column-excluding-the-heading-line)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - format a whole column excluding the heading line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730842/excel-vba-format-a-whole-column-excluding-the-heading-line)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I optimize this vba loop code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111276/how-can-i-optimize-this-vba-loop-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your strings are valid (Excel Recognizable Format) dates, you can try below:

```
With Range("A8:A" & lastrow)
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "mm/d/yyyy"
End With
```

This is solely based on the scenario you described in your question.
Posted as answer since, links posted didn't discuss this approach. HTH.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, that works.  I edited slightly to:

With Range("A8:A" & lastRow)

because my data started in row 8.